# URL Encoding issues on Windows

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, url, encoding, urlencode

```
            ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            String utf8PackageName = URLEncoder.encode(packageName, "UTF8").replace("+", "%20");
            LOGGER.debug("utf8PackageName : {}", utf8PackageName);
            objectMetadata.setContentDisposition("attachment; filename*=UTF-8''" + utf8PackageName);
            request.setMetadata(objectMetadata);
```

I am trying to use above code to set content disposition in request for an object upload to S3. Problem I am facing is that URLEncoder.encode() is giving different values on windows and linux machines and it sets different content disp values.

I tried to decode utf8PackageName generated on windows machine using online decoders but it decodes to a different values.

E.g. (JAVA 8)

äöööüüüüüü => (Linux) : %C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%B6%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%BC%C3%BC%C3%BC%C3%BC%C3%BC : Decoding works fine

äöööüüüüüü => (Windows) : %C3%83%C2%A4%C3%83%C2%B6%C3%83%C2%B6%C3%83%C2%B6%C3%83%C2%BC%C3%83%C2%BC%C3%83%C2%BC%C3%83%C2%BC%C3%83%C2%BC%C3%83%C2%BC : Decoding does not work fine

I observed that in case of windows, every %C3 is replaced by %C3%83%C2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's evident the value on Windows of `packageName` which I take to be a `String` (assuming you are using `URLEncoder` from the Java standard library) contains 'characters' that are actually already a UTF8 encoding (i.e. really bytes and not characters). Whatever you did to produce/obtain that value contains something wrong, but we (I) have no idea what you did.

Comment: Although my issue is fixed, The packageName was obtained by reading it from an API with default charset but just a question, How did you come to know it was already UTF8-encoded?

Comment: %C3%83%C2%A4 is the UTF8-URL-encoding for the two bytes C3 A4 which is itself the UTF8 encoding of the character U+00E4 ä (small A w/diaeresis). Similarly for the rest. Usually Java's default charset on Windows is cp1252 (a single-byte code similar to Latin-1); if you 'decoded' data that was actually UTF8 using that (unmatching) charset you would get this result.